# c# Send Email through Exchange server 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, exchange-server

I am trying to write a code that will send email through my exchange server 2010 
and i get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' occurred in
>   System.dll

I confirmed sending anonymous email on my exchange server and all my information is correct (ip, port, username and password).

But still unable to make sending.

Here is the code i am using in c#:

```
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 25;
        client.Host = "myip";

        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 10000;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("myEmail", "SendToEmail", "test","test" );
        mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

        client.Send(mm);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can send emails using the Exchange Web Services API (EWS). EWS is a set of old fashioned ASMX web services hosted on the same server as OWA. Microsoft has even published a managed API wrapper for EWS.

Here is an example on how to send emails using EWS: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Send-Email-with-Exchange-50189e57

Usually EWS can be found at http://yourexchangeserver/ews/exchange.asmx but with the managed API you can use autodiscovery to automatically find the address of EWS on your Exchange server.

Here is an overview where things like autodiscovery are explained.

Update regarding Exchange 2003:

You can access the Exchange 2003 mail store via HTTP using WebDAV. WebDAV is a bit of a pain to use because you may have to use Forms Based Authentication (FBA) if that is what your OWA installation requires (in comparison EWS can use Windows Authentication even if OWA on Exchange 2007/2010 is using FBA).

I have never tried sending mails using WebDAV for Exchange (although I have used WebDAV for a number of other things) but I found an example on MSDN that you may want to try. It uses Windows Authentication so it will not work if your Exchange 2003 OWA is set up to use FBA. If you need to use FBA let me know - I may have some sample code somewhere that you can use.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your respond i did everying right and i am using now the Exchange Web Services API (EWS). and now i get this error: An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll                                                       and its says that somehting worng with my TLS/SSL. waitng for your help thank you!

Comment: Are you using the Exchange Name? Or the IP address to hit the exchange? I believe try switching it to the other one that you are not using right now because mostly the certificates are related to Names and not the IP address for the server so try switching. I hope it helps.